# Cannot connect to remote SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

A client of mine gave me a server name which is fully qualified `[servername].somedomain.net`
to try to connect to their SQL Server instance over VPN.

So I tried, using the username and password they gave me. No luck. I can ping it but cannot connect, I get the error that the username and password is incorrect.

So I log onto the actual server, verify that my login is in security and has rights and it appears there. `Workgroup\mylogin` and it appears that `workgroup\` actually is the same as `somedomain.net\mylogin`. Because when I try to add `somedomain.net\mylogin`, it resorts to saying that it's already added which is `workgroup\mylogin`.

Not sure what else to check here. I gave myself sysadmin role in SQL Server. I can ping the server's IP.

I looked at how they are authenticating me and they have my user in SQL Server set up to use Windows Auth. Well, the error I get is that it cannot trust cross domain when trying to use windows auth when I try to connect locally here in my management studio. I'm connected tot their VPN so what could be the problem?

They're not available right now to try to troubleshoot it and I'm just curious what else I might try to try and resolve this on my own if I can.

Answer (score 21):

Basically, when you failed to connect to your SQL Server, the issue could be:

1. Network issue,
2. SQL Server configuration issue.
3. Firewall issue
4. Client driver issue
5. Application configuration issue.
6. Authentication and logon issue.

**Step 1: Network issue**

You might be able to make local connection without a working network, but that's a special case. For remote connection, a stable network is required. The first thing to trouble shoot SQL connectivity issues is to make sure the network we rely on is workable and stable. Please run the following commands:

ping -a     (use -4 and -6 for IPv4 and IPv6 specifically)
ping -a 
nslookup (type your local and remote machine name and IP address multiple times)

Be careful to see any mismatch on the returned results. If you are not able to ping your target machine, it has high chance that either the network is broken or the target machine is not running. It's possible the target machine is behind a firewall and the firewall blocks the packets sent by ping, though. Windows firewall does not block ping (ECHO) packet by default. The correctness of DNS configuration on the network is vital to SQL connection. Wrong DNS entry could cause of all sorts of connectivity issue later. See this link for example, "Cannot Generate SSPI Context" error message, Poisoned DNS.

**Step 2: SQL Server configuration issue**

You need to make sure the target SQL Server is running and is listening on appropriate protocols. You can use SQL Server Configuration Manager (SCM) to enable protocols on the server machine. SQL Server supports Shared Memory, Named Pipes, and TCP protocols (and VIA which needs special hardware and is rarely used). For remote connection, NP and/or TCP protocols must be enabled. Once you enabled protocols in SCM, please make sure restart the SQL Server.

You can open errorlog file to see if the server is successfully listening on any of the protocol. The location of errorlog file is usually under:
%ProgramFile%Microsoft SQL Server/MSSQLxx.xxx/MSSQL/Log
If the target SQL instance is a named instance, you also need to make sure SQL Browser is running on the target machine. If you are not able to access the remote SQL Server, please ask your admin to make sure all these happen.

**Step 3: Firewall issue**

A firewall on the SQL Server machine (or anywhere between client and server) could block SQL connection request. An easy way to isolate if this is a firewall issue is to turn off firewall for a short time if you can. Long term solution is to put exception for SQL Server and SQL Browser.

For NP protocol, please make sure file sharing is in firewall exception list. Both file sharing and NP use SMB protocol underneath.
For TCP protocol, you need put the TCP port on which the SQL Server listens on into exception.
For SQL Browser, please put UDP port 1434 into exception.
Meanwhile, you can put sqlservr.exe and sqlbrowser.exe into exception as well, but this is not recommended. IPSec between machines that we are not trusted could also block some packets. Note that firewall should never be an issue for local connections.

**Step 4: Client driver issue**

At this stage, you can test your connection using some tools. The tests need to be done on client machine for sure.

First try:
telnet  
You should be able to telnet to the SQL server TCP port if TCP is enabled. Otherwise, go back to check steps 1-3. Then, use OSQL, SQLCMD, and SQL Management Studio to test sql connections. If you don't have those tools, please download SQL Express from Microsoft and you can get those tools for free.

OSQL (the one shipped with SQL Server 2000) uses MDAC.
OSQL (the one shipped with SQL Server 2005 & 2008) uses SNAC ODBC.
SQLCMD (shipped with SQL Server 2005 & 2008) uses SNAC OLEDB.
SQL Management Studio (shipped with SQL Server 2005 & 2008) uses SQLClient.

Possilbe command use be:
osql -E -SYour_target_machine\Your_instance for Windows Auth
osql -Uyour_user -SYour_target_machine\Your_instance for SQL Auth

SQLCMD also applies here. In addition, you can use “-Stcp:Your_target_machine, Tcp_port” for TCP,  “-Snp:Your_target_machine\Your_instance” for NP, and “-Slpc:Your_target_machine\Your_instance” for Shared Memory. You would know if it fails for all protocols or just some specific procotols.

At this stage, you should not see general error message such as error 26 and error 40 anymore. If you are using NP and you still see error 40 (Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server), please try the following steps:
a)       Open a file share on your server machine.
b)       Run “net view \your_target_machine” and “net use \your_target_machine\your_share”  (You can try Map Network Drive from Windows Explorer as well)
If you get failure in b), it's very likely you have OS/Network configuration issue, which is not SQL Server specific. Please search on internet to resolve this issue first.

You can try connection using both Windows Authentication and SQL Authentication. If the tests with all tools failed, there is a good chance that steps 1-3 were not set correctly, unless the failure is logon-related then you can look at step 6.

If you succeeds with some of the tools, but fails with other tools, it's probably a driver issue. You can post a question on our forum and give us the details.

You can also use “\windows\system32\odbcad32.exe” (which ships with Windows) to test connection by adding new DSN for various drivers, but that's for ODBC only.

**Step 5: Application issue**

If you succeed with steps 1-4 but still see failure in your application, it's likely a configuration issue in your application. Think about couple of possible issues here.
a) Is your application running under the same account with the account you did tests in step 4? If not, you might want to try testing in step 4 under that account or change to a workable service account for your application if possible.
b) Which SQL driver does your app use?
c) What's your connection string? Is the connection string compatible to your driver? Please check http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for reference.

**Step 6: Authentication and logon issue**
This is probably the most difficult part for sql connectivity issues. It's often related to the configuration on your network, your OS and your SQL Server database. There is no simple solution for this, and we have to solve it case by case. There are already several blogs in sql_protocols talking about some special cases and you can check them see if any of them applies to your case. Apart from that, things to keep in mind:
a) If you use SQL auth, mixed authentication must be enabled. Check this page for reference http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx
b) Make sure your login account has access permission on the database you used during login ("Initial Catalog" in OLEDB).
c) Check the eventlog on your system see if there is more information

**Reference:** http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-connectivity-issues.aspx

Sorry for this wall of text, i hope that something from here can help you solve your issue!

Regards.

Comment: I said I can create a new SQL User on THEIR side in SQL Server Security for that SQL Server instance (se SQL Auth to that database server)...and can auth to their database that way.

Comment: Phew after a lot of research ended up on your answer, that made me suspect SQL Browser.  I don't know how this service was stopped and disabled. Enabling and starting it worked for me to establish the remote connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access that server you are going to need a domain account from that domain or use SQL authentication. I would recommend just using SQL authentication - it's a lot more straight forward - if they allow it.

Comment: I'm using SQL Auth but just trying to get the original domain user account which for some reason when I add my domain account with them to  SQL Server security, it adds it as workgroup\myusername.  So it looks my domain account is added to SQL Server security which is why I can't figure out when over VPN I can't auth to it via Windows Auth option.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken the reason `Workgroup` is working is because that's the generic default name for Microsoft's workgroups for machines that aren't joined to the domain. However, I am 99.99% confident that won't ever work because the SQL Server can't validate it with the Domain Server on the domain.

Comment: That's not necessarily the case.  I don't know what sysadmin logic goes into it, but we have two domains, and user domain2\Bob_Smith *can* connect to a server on the other domain if he enters SQLDB01.domain1.corp.com.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, other machines could connect to sql server but one computer was not connecting and displaying the error "a network related or instance specific error...", the problem was solved when I changed the network protocol in the login window of SSMS, in advanced options from TCP/IP to Named Pipes. Please see the below screenshots.

[image: Connect to server dialog of SSMS - click options]

[image: Select Named pipes in network protocol dialog on connection properties tab]

Please note that you should be on the same domain, and your credentials should be valid on the server.