# SQL Server Remote Connection

Tags: sql-server, routes, database-connection, connection-string

I have configurated SQL Server 2012 Express like MSDN and other people says. But I cant make connection from outside of local network.
So I can connect like this: `192.168.0.101/SQLEXPRESS`, but `my_public_ip/SQLEXPRESS` doesnt work, even other options `my_public_ip:1433/SQLEXPRESS` or `my_public_ip/SQLEXPRESS,1433` and etc. I try connect form my local computer to himself.

Of course I tried [Cannot connect to remote SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12041629/cannot-connect-to-remote-sql-server) and other Google advices.
So my configuration:
firewall - off
virtual server on router (and I tryied Port Triggering) - 1433
SQL Server Configuration Manager - SQL Server Browser Running (Log on as Local service), TCP/IP enabled.

Where I can be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.

After I posted question I tried to find if port not realy 1433. And I was right! It was 6080. So I made virtual server with 6080 port on router and had connected my_public_ip\SQLEXPRESS,6080

Thanks